# Appropriate return type for an async http request? IO[Future[Response]] or Future[Response]? Or some alternative?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, monads, future, scalaz

For the following hypothetical function (in scala), what would be the appropriate return type in functional programming?

```
def execute(req: HttpRequest): <UnknownResultType>
```

I would assume `IO[Future[Response]]`, since we have both networking side effects as well as asynchronicity.

Since this may be a bit cumbersome (a monad wrapped in a monad, even with monad transformers), is there a better abstraction in FP for handling this?

Comment: `Future` is often used like `IO` in Scala (i.e. to represent any old kind of effect). Even in Scalaz the idiomatic type for this would be `Task`, which is equivalent in the relevant respects to the standard library's `Future`.

Comment: @TravisBrown But I don't think that would be referentially transparent. Because we wouldn't be able to replace multiple invocations of `execute(req)` with the result of invoking it once, which would be a future. Specifically, each invocation of `execute(req)` would send a separate http request, whereas the future result would only do it once and cache the result. Using IO, on the other hand, would retain RT.

Comment: Okay, my "in the relevant respects" was overstated a bit—you're right that Scala's `Future` doesn't give you RT (while `Task` does). In any case I think you probably don't want representations of both `IO` and `Future`, you want a RT version of `Future` (like `Task`).

Comment: @TravisBrown I think you could combine your two comments as a valid answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Travis Brown said, the most idiomatic way to return a pure asynchronous computation in Scala is to use `scalaz.concurrent.Task`, which you can find in the `scalaz-concurrent` library.

With `Task` your function will look as follows:

```
def execute(req: HttpRequest): Task[Response]
```

`execute` is a pure function: no side effects will happen until you call `Task.run` or similar methods.

For good introduction to `Task` see [this great article](http://timperrett.com/2014/07/20/scalaz-task-the-missing-documentation/).